# Let $f: \mathbb R^+ \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a function defined $f(x) = x^p$ for arbitrary real $p$. Show that the function is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification, continuity

Proposition I would like to prove:

> **Proposition**. Let $f: \mathbb R^+ \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a function defined $f(x) = x^p$ for arbitrary real $p$. Show that the function is continuous.

**My attempt**.

We will utilize following two lemmas:

1. Let $f: \mathbb R^+ \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a function defined $f(x) = x^p$ for arbitrary real $p$. We have $x^p \rightarrow 1$ as $x \rightarrow1$.
2. For arbitrary function $g$, $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0}g(x) = L$ if and only if for any sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ (where all elements are in the domain of $g$) that converges to $x_0$, the sequence $(g(a_n))_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $L$.

Take any positive real $x_0$ and arbitrary real $p$.

Take any sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ that converges to $x_0$ and $a_n \in \mathbb R^{+}$ for all $n$. Since all elements are positive (more importantly, **non-zero**), the sequence $(a_n/a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ exists and converges to $1$. By lemma $1$ and $2$, it follows that $\bigr((a_n/a_n)^p\bigr)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $1$. That is, we have

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(a_n/a_n)^p =  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(a_n)^p \cdot \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(1/a_n)^p= 1 $$

Multiplying by $x_0^p$ gives

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(a_n)^p \cdot \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(x_0/a_n)^p = x_0^p$$

Using limit laws, we can see that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(x_0/a_n)^p$ is just $1$, so

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(a_n)^p  = x_0^p$$

$(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ was an arbitrary sequence, hence by lemma $2$ we can see that $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0}f(x) = x_0^p$. And since $x_0$ was arbitrary too, we see that the function is continuous. $\Box$

**Is it correct?**

Comment: $a_n/a_n=1$. So this seem  not very helpful. I would suggest to consider $a_n/x_0$ instead.

Comment: @JensSchwaiger But $a_n/a_n=1 \implies \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n/a_n = 1 \implies \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (a_n/a_n)^p = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n^p \cdot \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 1/a_n^p = 1$, which then allowed me to arrive at the desired result. Or is there a mistake somewhere?

Comment: $(a_n/a_n)^p$ converges to $1$ indeed. But it doesn't follow that $a_n^p$ converges at all.